# Many to many association and search

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models: `Event` `Lineup` `Artist`

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lineups
  has_many :artists, through: :lineups
end

class Lineup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :event
  belongs_to :artist
end

class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :events, through: :lineups
  has_many :lineups
end
```

Artists have `name` attribute.

Edit: My question wasn't precise enough.

How can I find all events with, for example, these 3 artists's names: 
`artist1`, `artist2`, `artist3` ?

With these events:

```
event1.artists.pluck(:name)
=> ['artist1', 'artist2', 'artist3']

event2.artists.pluck(:name)
=> ['artist1', 'artist2', 'artist3', 'artist4']

event3.artists.pluck(:name)
=> ['artist1', 'artist2', 'artist4']

event4.artists.pluck(:name)
=> ['artist1', 'artist2']
```

Result should be `event1` and `event2`

Answer (score 3):

You will use `joins` like:

```
Event
  .joins(:artists)
  .where( artists: { name: ['artist1', 'artist2', 'artist3'] } )
```

Comment: Your query selects event even when `event.artists ==['artist1']`, I want events where I have all these artists in lineup (but it can have some more artists)

Comment: @MarcinDoliwa Thanks. Then why do you think, the above query is not what you want. I think what I wrote is what you want.

Comment: Beacause for this join you wrote I get 10 results: `Event.joins(:artists).where( artists: {name: ['artist1', 'artist2', 'artist3']}).pluck('events.name')` result is `["event1", "event1", "event1", "event2", "event2", "event2", "event3", "event3", "event4", "event4"]`

Comment: SQL for it looks like this: `SELECT "events".* FROM "events" INNER JOIN "lineups" ON "lineups"."event_id" = "events"."id" INNER JOIN "artists" ON "artists"."id" = "lineups"."artist_id" WHERE "artists"."name" IN ('artist1', 'artist2', 'artist3')`

Comment: @MarcinDoliwa And you are expecting the number of events to appear? remember you have many-to-many in place.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your model is holding `@event = Event.artists.all`

Go in your view and use this

```
<% @event.each do |x| %>
   <%= x.name %>
<% end %>
```

That will print out all the names of every artist.

If you're asking for specifically artist1, artist2, artist3... use this

`@event.where(name: 'artist name goes here')`

Comment: The OP said, *Artists have `name` attribute*

Comment: yeah I was basing it off `@artists = Event.artists.all` Then an each loop to find all the artists. I think I misunderstood his problem though, I realize your solution makes a lot more sense

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this based on Arup's answer.

```
lineup = ['artist', 'artist2', 'artist3']
Event.joins(:artists)
     .where(artists: { name: lineup})
     .group("events.id")
     .having("count(events.id) = ?", lineup.length)
```